# how to reorder my array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have a array that contains all the months in a year like so:

```
[January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December];
```

When the user types a months in a textfield say like they type "May", I take whats in the textfield and store it as a string.
Now I want to reorder my array with May being the first index so my array would now look like this now:

```
[May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December];
```

I don't care about the months January - March.
I'm having trouble reordering my array correctly? Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What I would do is get the index of the month you got in the text field and remove any object before that one, that way you only have the ones from the one you typed

Comment: ye i see. what the user typed is stored as a string but using this call [months array indexOfObject:(id)obj] asks for an object. How to i deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
NSString *monthString = @"May";
NSUInteger monthIndex = [monthsArray indexOfObject:monthString];
NSArray *trimmedMonthsArray = nil;
if (monthIndex != NSNotFound) {
    trimmedMonthsArray = [monthsArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(monthIndex, [monthArray count] - monthIndex)];
}
```

As you see it's not so much about reordering (actually it's not about reordering at all) but about cutting out a subarray.

If instead of getting a new trimmed array you want to modify the original mutable array, do this:

```
NSString *monthString = @"May";
NSUInteger monthIndex = [monthsArray indexOfObject:monthString];
if (monthIndex != NSNotFound) {
    [monthsArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, monthIndex)];
}
```

Comment: ok i see what ur doing. i dont know what the user is going to be typing so it wont be always "May". How would I change it so that I find the right month that the user typed in the textfield?

Comment: Edited answer to make it more clear. Just set `monthString` the string that the user typed. E.g. via `monthString = [textfield stringValue];` on OS X or `monthString = textfield.text;` on iOS.

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't work. NSString *textFieldString = userTextfield.text;  NSUInteger *monthIndex = [monthsArray indexOfObject:textFieldString]; it gives a very high index value that makes no sense.

Comment: This *strange* high value is most likely the respective value defined as NSNotFound, which is returned by `indexOfObject:` in case no matching object was found in the array. In other words: you mistyped the month's name. Read [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:) on said method for more insight.

Comment: I guess i dont understand why [monthsArray indexOfObject:@"May"] return the correct index and [monthsArray indexOfObject:textFieldString] doesn't when textFieldString contains the exact same string. I guess i need to keep learning. thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"%@", textFieldString);` and check if it really contains nothing but `@"May"`. If the content of `textFieldString` is equal to `@"May"`, then `indexOfObject:textFieldString` must return the same index as `indexOfObject:@"May"`.

Comment: haha u were right. I actually checked that earlier but didn't checked if there was any spaces. the textfieldString was @"May " instead of @"May". thanks!